# Html, css, и про верстку вообще вопрос.

Tags: css

Господа, тут такая ситуация противная: есть сайт, и он сверстан типа адаптивно. Ясен день, косяков там over дофига, и это видно даже мне, абсолютному нубу в этих делах, но работа есть работа.

Задача: сделать таблицу читабельной с телефона, причем она должна быть видна вся и сразу. Начиная от заголовков а-ля "коллекции прошлых сезонов" (весьма большой заголовок, а таких в одной таблице 3) до маразма с пояснениями шапки в скобках. Менять формулировку они не хотят. Таблицу очень важно оставлять в том виде, в котором она есть (то есть вариант, когда информация подается блоками, типа тут все об этом, а вот ниже блок и все о другом - не приемлемо).

Мобилки на overflow: scroll как-то вообще не реагируют. Сама таблица не сжимается, а уходит за грани дисплея. Выставляла min-width:400px; и overflow:visible для body - на компе scroll работает, а в телефоне, опять-таки, нет, и visible все так же уходит за границы дисплея. 
Пыталась состряпать ее div, но в итоге они все уплывают в мобильной версии друг под друга. В общем, я исчерпала свои поверхностные знания. 
Помогите кто, а?

P.S. Не знаю, как это называется, но как сделать, чтобы хотя бы можно по экрану страницу таскать? Ну типа ведешь влево, и скрытая левая часть открывается, а правая скрывается? Не знаю, как это сформулировать даже. Или может просто подскажете перечень свойств, которые вообще за это отвечают?

Заранее спасибо за любую информацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не имея кода и\или ссылки на ресурс, сложно сказать что-то конструктивное, но я всё-таки попробую дать рекомендацию, как привести это в "более-менее" приемлемый вид:

**1)** Поиграйте шириной окна в браузере на десктопе и найдите "точку", где десктопная версия переходит в адаптивную (очень часто это 640px).

**2)** Укажите в шапке ("header") сайта такую строчку:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640" />
```

где 640 и есть эта точка.

**3)** Создайте в стилях (CSS) такое правило в самом низу (очень важно, чтобы не перебивать потом !important):

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    /* css here*/
}
```

**4)** Теперь у Вас есть возможность работать только с "мобильной" вёрсткой, не "замарав" обычную. Тут и таблицу можно превратить в блок и т.д.

**5)** Если на мобилах нет скроллинга, то проверьте у html и body должны быть такие стили, как:

```
position: relative;
overflow: visible;
```

**6)** Также на всех современных мобильных устройствах, браузер - webkit, и у него есть очень полезное свойство для скролла: `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`, при условии, что блок `overflow: visible/scroll/auto;`.

Comment: спасибо, многое прояснилось.